# regex for last name - how to improve efficiency and length and only allow 50 characters

Tags: regex, jsonschema

I have this regex that deals with last names with hyphen or apostrophe, but it's just really long and I'm not sure how to easily fix it without more research. I've spent several hours on this already and while it works, I'd like to clean it up a bit. I am including this in a json schema. I'd also like to limit the total number of characters to 50. I know you can do that with {1,50} but I don't know how to use that with a complex regex. Here's what I have currently:

`^[a-zA-Z]+((-[a-zA-Z]+)*('[a-zA-Z]+)*|('[a-zA-Z]+)*(-[a-zA-Z]+)*)$`

and my test data:

```
5               -- should fail
foster              -- should match
foster steve            -- should match (EDIT: should not match)
foster-morrison             -- should match
hello               -- should match
*RKER(($(#$)#$#L$KLK#$*     -- should fail
dfkfsdkfskdfjksjfksfksjfskjfksjfskfksjfksfksfskfd   -- should match
jkddkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkfdkd-ffddfdfdfdgggfgfgfgggggggg  -- should match
jkddkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkskdldkfdlkfdfkdfkdlkdkdkd-ffddfdfdfdgggfgfgfgggggggd   -- should fail
dkfkerksf------aaa-----     -- should fail
test---me           -- should fail
foster-mo           -- should match
f-morrison          -- should match
griffith-joiner         -- should match
test-               -- should fail
-dkd                -- should fail
d'andre             -- should match
d'andre-jordan          -- should match
jordan-d'andre          -- should match
```

Comment: You could try `^(?=.{1,50})[a-zA-Z']+(?:[- ][a-zA-Z']+)*$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/urtXqg/1)

Comment: Shouldn't `jkddkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkdkskdldkfdlkfdfkdfkdlkdkdkd-ffddfdfdfdgggfgfgfggggggg` fail since it is 76 long? Same goes for that next example...

Comment: true! Edited question..

Comment: I think that the [`maxLength`](http://json-schema.org/latest/json-schema-validation.html#rfc.section.6.3.1) would be of interest because counting in regex is hard

Comment: You can use [`^([a-zA-Z][ '-]?)*[a-zA-Z]+$`](https://regex101.com/r/mAXngd/1/) to enforce the pattern and `maxLength` to enforce the 50 total chars.

Comment: Excellent suggestions - I didn't realize the json schema had a max length like that. The above ^([a-zA-Z]['-]?)*[a-zA-Z]+$ without the space worked perfectly. Just took 1197 steps for my test suite though. 736 steps if I take out the two long test cases and match on maxLength.

Comment: Why did you remove the space from my regex? You wrote `foster steve            -- should match`

Comment: Oops - typo foster steve should NOT match.

Comment: Some of your comments spattered around:  `correct - test'''me should fail as well` and `Your initial suggestion of ^[a-zA-Z']+(?:[-][a-zA-Z']+)*$ without the max length and ability to match on spaces is more efficient than your answer above` and the canned `Thanks but lengthy and add'l steps to find matches` you put on every ones answer. Throw in that you've accepted an answer that you contradict leaves me to give you a _DOWNVOTE_. Sorry, had to do it. I suggest you learn regex.

Comment: Wow. That's harsh @sln. I'm here to learn more about regex because I haven't worked with it much. I'd read up on regex before posting, and that's how I was able to get the solution I did. And there was several very helpful answers. The accepted answer was accepted because thefourthbird commented on how to write it better first and checking the steps required at regex101.com showed it to be the most performant. Nick's answer was really good and I appreciated his effort, along with everyone else. Sorry my question wasn't perfect and that I thanked everyone for contributing. Bad day for you?

Comment: "I suggest you learn regex." - @sln. This is just unreasonable. I read up for several hours actually on regex sites and had actually never even heard of regex101.com before I started my research. I had no knowledge that any site actually showed the steps required to find matches either. Your comment has a lot of tone, and sorry I didn't pick your answer, but it just didn't perform as fast as the two others. I actually upvoted your answer, and kept the upvote there despite your criticism, but I see your answer is at 0 because probably someone else downvoted it (not me).

Comment: @sfors - I'm sorry, you're using big words when you talk about regex, like _performant_ and _number of steps_. These are the words a regex newbie uses because they have nothing to do with the real-time performance of regular expressions when doing a comparison of similar expressions. The big problem new regex users have is they don't know enough to actually express their questions that make sense as well as understanding answers submitted. It's not your fault, but since you're all over the place, I thought I'd remind you how far you've actually gone ..

Comment: @sln - so you're saying regex101.com's "number of steps" isn't there to assist developers with efficiency and performance? If not, then why is it there? I'll agree with you that I'm a regex newbie - no doubt there - but I. am. learning...

Comment: @sfors - No, you won't see any website claiming the `"number of steps"` as an indicator of relative performance. Not all _steps_ are equal. It's just like code where the number of lines is not an indicator either. As to `to assist developers with efficiency and performance` I'm sure that doesn't pertain to regular expressions as it doesn't pertain to any language. You either learned enough to be productive or you haven't. The premise that  online regex testing sites have any helpful value at all is a bunch of crap, they don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your current pattern does not match all examples is because due to the [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` it will match either (where *chars* is a-zA-Z):

`chars-chars'chars` or `chars'chars-chars`

That will only match `d'andre-jordan` or `jordan-d'andre` and does not take a space or matching only upper or lowercase chars a- into account

To assert a length of 1 - 50 characters you could use a positive lookahead `(?=.{1,50}$)`

Instead of the alternation, you could make use of repeating patterns where the `'` can not occur 2 times after each other and match a hyphen or space inbetween.

```
^(?=.{1,50}$)[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)*(?:[- ][a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z])*)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XkfOzS/1)

As an alternative per request, my first suggested pattern without the lookahead is:

```
^[a-zA-Z']+(?:[- ][a-zA-Z']+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Se5hO8/1)

Comment: Since `test---me` should fail, I think the OP would want `test'''me` to fail as well. That's why I didn't go with this approach.

Comment: correct -      test'''me should fail as well. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @sfors I have updated the answer to not match `test''me`

Comment: Thanks but lengthy and add'l steps to find matches.

Comment: Your initial suggestion of `^[a-zA-Z']+(?:[-][a-zA-Z']+)*$` without the max length and ability to match on spaces is more efficient than your answer above. Please add this to the answer as an alternative and I'll accept this one as it's the most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like this:

```regex
^(?=.{1,50}$)[a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)?(?:[- ][a-zA-Z]+(?:'[a-zA-Z]+)?)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qdKWF4/1).

And if you want to support multiple (but not consecutive) hyphens/spaces, you may replace the last `?` with a `*`.

Comment: Thanks but lengthy and add'l steps to find matches.

Answer (score 0):

`(?=^.{1,50}$)^[a-zA-Z]+([ \-'][a-zA-Z]+)*?$`

Cleaned-up regex that matches all of your test cases (and a few extras like test'''me), and asserts 50 character limit. **Note that this also matches longer, complicated last-names,** like jordan-d'andre-joe-b'bob; if this is not desired behavior, feel free to let me know.

How's it work?

```
The regex is in 3 main chunks:
(?=^.{1,50}$)
             ^[a-zA-Z]+
                       ([ \-'][a-zA-Z]+)*?$


First chunk breakdown:
(?=^.{1,50}$)

(?=         )    - positive lookahead, asserts that the following holds true
   ^       $     - ensure that between the start and end of the line...
    .            - ...any character...
     {1,50}      - ...exists, and there's between 1 and 50 of the "any character" token


Second chunk breakdown:
^[a-zA-Z]+

^             - assert that this begins at the start of the line
 [a-zA-Z]     - match any letter
         +    - get as many as you can, but be sure to get at least one


Third chunk breakdown:
([ \-'][a-zA-Z]+)*?$

                   $    - assert this happens at the end of the line
(               )*?     - match this entire group zero or more times, but only as much as is necessary. 
                          - in specific, *? lets you match between zero and unlimited times (*) as few times as possible (?).
                            this is because for names WITHOUT spaces, apostrophes, or hyphens, this section of 
                            the regex can be discarded (hence, zero or more times) which leaves behind only
                            the first and second parts of the regex - character count and name. however, in names that include many 
                            iterations and combinations of spaces, hyphens, and apostrophes, the regex can and will grow as needed,
                            continuing to match them as long as it doesn't hit the end of the line.
                          - note that without the $, this never matches, and will always miss any name with spaces, apostrophes, or hyphens.
 [ \-']                 - match a space, a literal hyphen, or an apostrophe, once - no back-to-back symbols
       [a-zA-Z]+        - match one or more letter
```

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/M9ysZS/4)

---

I believe I also saw in a previous edit that you were interested in cleaning up the regex, though I'm not sure if that includes efficiency. Either way, though, if you're going to count characters, it's important to be aware of the possibility for catastrophic backtracking. [This article](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) describes catastrophic backtracking, which is where a regex tracks behind itself over and over trying to find a match that doesn't exist. I actually encountered one while working on this regex; if you use a lookbehind instead of a lookahead for the character limit, the regex runs so slowly that many debuggers will refuse to run it at all.

**Always be as exact as possible about what you're searching for.** Though I didn't see it in your example (good on ya!) if you're worried about efficiency, wildcards can be rough on your regex. `.` is a powerful tool, but it pays off to be more precise; more wildcards often mean more backtracking.

Let's examine a situation where this could be a real problem. Suppose we have a string, `abaabababbabababaabababb`. The string has one or more a, followed by one or more b, and this pattern repeats exactly ten times. Valid strings include:

```
abababababababababab
aaaaaaaaaabababababababababab
aabbaabbaabbaabbaabbaabbaabbaabbaabbaabb
```

We know "one or more a" is `a+`, "one or more b" is `b+`, "repeating pattern" is `(a+b+)`, and "10 times" is `(a+b+){10}` - cool! [This regex matches all 3 strings in 96 steps.](https://regex101.com/r/JoayPt/1)

But... what if we want to broaden it so that ANY two characters work, not just a and b? It's so tempting to do `(.+.+){10}` Looks innocent, right? Nope. This can't even handle *the shortest valid string* without catastrophic backtracking.

Once it reaches the end of the string and finds "no match", the last `.` gives up one character to the previous `.` and checks if it's valid (it's not). They do this again and again, all the way down the chain, with exponentially more things to try the longer your string gets. Even if there's a valid match, the system may take seconds or even minutes to find it; regex101 simply refuses to try. If you remove one letter, though, it's just short enough for the website to consider, revealing that it takes more than [*1.5 million steps*](https://regex101.com/r/JoayPt/2) to figure out there's no match. Heaven help you if you deploy this on a hundred-character invalid string.

Wildcards plus unlimited quantifiers can cause some serious backtracking issues. The more precise you are, the better you'll do. Good luck!

Comment: This seems to be written very well and super clean. It's also the most efficient I've seen so far by a good margin. Can you explain the use of the *? in the expression? An a* matches zero or more of a, and a? matches zero or one of a, but I don't understand the use of them connected together.

Comment: @sfors updated the answer with a bit more info. The tl;dr is that `*?` lets the regex include as many additions of `<space>`, `-`, and `'` (plus letters) as it wants to, but since `*` is "zero or more", the regex is not *required* to do so. That's why it'll match `sir joe-the-fourth'st-man guy` as well as plain old `frank`.

Comment: You can omit the `?` in `*?$` as you are asserting the end of the string. You could also make the group that you repeat non capturing g `(?:` or else you will have a group containing the value of the last iteration which is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the additional tweaks @Thefourthbird. I modified it to be `^[a-zA-Z]+([\-'][a-zA-Z]+)*$` because as @monkeyzeus pointed out, I can specify max length in my json schema. Replaced the `*?$` with `*$` and it seems to perform the same matches. what do you mean make the group that you repeat non capturing?

Comment: Matches `s'o-u'l t-r'a'i n`

Answer (score 0):

I would do it the easy way

`(?m)^(?:(?<!^)(?:(?!\1|\2|\3)(['])|(?!\1|\2|\3)([-])|(?!\1|\2|\3)([ ]))(?!$)|[a-zA-Z]){1,50}$`

https://regex101.com/r/TiRqeZ/1

```
 (?m)
 ^ 
 (?:
      (?<! ^ )
      (?:
           (?! \1 | \2 | \3 )
           ( ['] )                       # (1)
        |  (?! \1 | \2 | \3 )
           ( [-] )                       # (2)
        |  (?! \1 | \2 | \3 )
           ( [ ] )                       # (3)
      )
      (?! $ )
   |  
      [a-zA-Z] 
 ){1,50}
 $
```

Comment: Thanks, but lengthy and takes a lot of steps.